# How to add a TFS group to a ProcessTemplate

Tags: tfs-process-template

I have a TFS group (not an active directory group) that I need to add to every project we create in TFS. I open the XML file and add the group but when I create the project there is no one in it. If I check TFS they are in the group but not the group TFS added.

```
 <group name="Business Analysts" description="All our BA's">
      <permissions>
        <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_WRITE" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
        <permission name="DELETE" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="PUBLISH_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="DELETE_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="ADMINISTER_BUILD" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="START_BUILD" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="EDIT_BUILD_STATUS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="UPDATE_BUILD" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="CREATE_CHILDREN" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="WORK_ITEM_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="WORK_ITEM_WRITE" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_PLANS" class="CSS_NODE" allow="false" />
        <permission name="VIEW_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_ENVIRONMENTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_CONFIGURATIONS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
        <permission name="CREATE_CHILDREN" class="ITERATION_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="DELETE" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="DELETE" class="ITERATION_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="ITERATION_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_WRITE" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
        <permission name="GENERIC_WRITE" class="ITERATION_NODE" allow="true" />
      </permissions>
      <members>
        <member name="[DefaultCollection]\Business Analysts"></member>
      </members>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where Business Analysts exists.
TFS Groups exist at the server level, at the collection level, and at the project level. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
For instance, you might try:

```
member name="[SERVER]\Business Analysts"
```

This references the TFS Server as the "domain" instead of DefaultCollection.